# DataConnection.HandleError while upgrading kentico 8.2 to 9

Tags: upgrade, kentico

[image]
it happens on each every page . I have no idea about this error. Any help?

Comment: Seems that the database got updated but DLLs did not. Can you check versions of assemblies in your bin folder? Are they 9.*? Can you also turn on debug in your web.config and show us your stack trace (to see where is the error coming from)? Or, if it happens only on live site, follow Brenden's answer...

Answer (score 3):

The column `SiteName` was removed in v9.  [Here's an article](https://devnet.kentico.com/articles/database-changes-in-kentico-9-how-to-deal-with-missing-views) talking about it.  [Here are the release notes](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Release+notes+-+Kentico+9) for v9.  So you'll have to log into the Admin site and to to Page Templates and modify your listing repeaters in there to remove the `SiteName` column.

**UPDATE**

What you can do to get a list of templates which have `SiteName` is to run a SQL script like so:

`SELECT *
FROM CMS_PageTemplate
WHERE PageTemplateWebParts like '%sitename%'`

This will give you a list of templates which have webparts that the property or value of `SiteName` in them.

Answer (score 1):

Did your database upgrade show any errors?  Maybe check your version in the database vs your site structure and see if they match.  I think just from the looks of it, your database upgrade didn't complete or had an issue.  You could try rolling back to your backup and reupgrading maybe by running the upgrade query on your database.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't believe this is correct at all because as I stated in my answer the release notes specifically state the `SiteName` column was removed in v9.  Rolling back and running the upgrade is only busy work.  The OP needs to go through the templates and update his properties.